# Completely random behaviour of setting texture on sf::RectangleShape

Tags: c++, sfml

In my game, I have a class `view::Player` that represents player token moving on board and player label that displays his stats. Tokens are fine, but once I implemented labels (`sf::RectangleShape`), strange things started to happen.

[image]

Those 4 rectangles are player labels, as you can see, just 2 of them has set texture. Now the fun begins, based on what `std::string` player name I choose before, 2nd rectangle sometimes has no texture as well. If I change number of players to 1, 2 or 3, only last one will have texture. I have no idea what is going on and why, so I need to start with very beggining of my app.

So to the entry point, class that creates `std::vector<std::string>` of player names, its written in console, rest of the game has GUI handled by SFML.

```
void NewGame::start() {
    std::cout << "***Welcome to Eurobusiness Board Game***\n" <<
        "How many players are going to play? [2, 3 or 4] \n";
    do {
        std::cin >> m_numberOfPlayers;
    } while (m_numberOfPlayers < 2 || m_numberOfPlayers > 4);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_numberOfPlayers; ++i) {
        bool isNameUnique;
        std::string name;
        std::cout << "Enter name of player nr " << i + 1 << "\n";       

        do {
            std::cin >> name;
            isNameUnique = true;
            if (m_playerNames.size() > 0) {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < m_playerNames.size(); ++i) {
                    if (name == m_playerNames[i]) {
                        std::cout << "Choose unique name for every player. \n";
                        isNameUnique = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        isNameUnique = true;
                    }
                }
            }           
        } while (!isNameUnique);    
        m_playerNames.push_back(name);
    }

    view::GameView newGameView(m_numberOfPlayers, m_playerNames);
}
```

From that, we go to `view::GameView` which is main class that handles drawing and interaction with user. It's constructor looks like that

```
view::GameView::GameView(int numberOfPlayers, std::vector<std::string>& playerNames)
    : m_game(numberOfPlayers, playerNames), m_numberOfPlayers(numberOfPlayers)
{
    m_data = std::make_unique<Data>();
    m_data->window.create(sf::VideoMode(APPLICATION_SCREEN_WIDTH, APPLICATION_SCREEN_HEIGHT), APPLICATION_TITLE, sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar);
    gameLoop();
}
```

And most important parts of header

```
namespace view {
    class GameView {
        logic::Game m_game;
        std::vector<view::Player> m_players;
    };
}
```

Player's names are passed to `logic::Game` which is main class that handles all the logic, here is constructor of this class

```
logic::Game::Game(size_t numberOfPlayers, std::vector<std::string>& playerNames)
    : m_numberOfPlayers(numberOfPlayers) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; ++i) {
        m_players.emplace_back(Player(playerNames[i]));
    }
}
```

Then important part of `logic::Game' header

```
namespace logic {
    class Game {
        std::vector<logic::Player> m_players;
        logic::Player& getPlayer(int i) { return m_players[i]; }
    };
}
```

So till now, I got `std::vector<logic::Player>` with created players by names passed from constructor in `logic::Game` and `std::vector<view::Player>` in `view::GameView` which has no elements yet. Before I step to placing items in this vector, here is my `view::Player` class.

```
namespace view {
    class Player {
        logic::Player* m_player;
        sf::CircleShape m_token;
        sf::RectangleShape m_label;
        sf::Texture m_texture;
    public:
        Player(logic::Player&);
        void create(sf::Color, int, int);
        sf::CircleShape& getToken() {
            return m_token;
        }
        sf::RectangleShape& getLabel() {
            return m_label;
        }
    };
}

view::Player::Player(logic::Player& player) {
    m_player = &player;

    if (!m_texture.loadFromFile(PLAYER_LABEL)) {
        std::cout << "Can't load texture.\n";
    }   
}

void view::Player::create(sf::Color color, 
    int labelPositionX, int labelPositionY) {

    m_token.setFillColor(color);
    m_token.setRadius(10);
    m_token.setPosition(STARTING_POSITION_X, STARTING_POSITION_Y);
    m_token.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);
    m_token.setOutlineThickness(2);
    m_token.setOrigin({ 20, 20 });

    m_label.setSize(sf::Vector2f(PLAYER_LABEL_WIDTH, PLAYER_LABEL_HEIGHT));
    m_label.setTexture(&m_texture);
    m_label.setPosition(labelPositionX, labelPositionY);
    m_label.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 140, 70));
}
```

With that, I go back to `view::GameView` where I have `createPlayers()` that is called in `initialise()` function, first thing after `gameLoop()` starts

```
void view::GameView::createPlayers() {
    sf::Color color;
    int labelPositionX = PLAYER_LABEL_POSITION_X;
    int labelPositionY;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_numberOfPlayers; ++i) {           
        if (i == 0) {
            color = sf::Color::Red;         
            labelPositionY = PLAYER_ONE_LABEL_POSITION_Y;
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            color = sf::Color::Blue;            
            labelPositionY = PLAYER_TWO_LABEL_POSITION_Y;
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            color = sf::Color::Green;           
            labelPositionY = PLAYER_THREE_LABEL_POSITION_Y;
        }
        if (i == 3) {
            color = sf::Color::Yellow;          
            labelPositionY = PLAYER_FOUR_LABEL_POSITION_Y;
        }
        m_players.push_back(view::Player(m_game.getPlayer(i)));
        m_players[i].create(color, labelPositionX, labelPositionY);         
    }   
}
```

And finnaly in `draw()`

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_numberOfPlayers; ++i) {
        this->m_data->window.draw(m_players[i].getToken());
        this->m_data->window.draw(m_players[i].getLabel());
}
```

I know its quite a lot of code but I honestly have no idea what to remove and then paste here, because random things make it even worse, like for example, I removed `m_token` initialisation from `view::Player::create()` and suddenly, 1st texture was loaded too but its `sf::IntRect` was set somewhere else. I dont know if there is a big flaw somewhere in design, or I simply made small misstake that I can't find.

Comment: `view::Player` and `logic::Player` are not the same objects, therefore, its not copy c-tor, just a c-tor that takes reference to another object as argument.

Comment: You are right, I misread the argument type.

Comment: @Emdzej93 `view::Player::Player(logic::Player& player) { m_player = &player;}` -- Is `&player` an address within a vector?  If so, you're in danger of that pointer becoming invalidated if that vector is resized.

Comment: If the problem appears random, and the behavior seems to change due to seemingly unrelated modifications, it's almost certainly because you have undefined behavior in your code. It's probable the problem is not even in the code you showed, it could be anywhere. Your problem would just be a symptom of another problem in a distant part of your code. It seems to me like the solution may be painstaking debugging and code review. If you use version control, see which version first has the problem and it may help narrow down where and when the problem originated.

Comment: @Emdzej93 -- *for (int i = 0; i < m_numberOfPlayers; ++i)* -- You're using `m_numberOfPlayers` to index into a vector.  Do not use extraneous, unnecessary variables like this, when the vector has `size()` to tell you the number of entries.  Why use vector::size()?  Because `vector::size()` never fails.  When you start to use extra variables to give you the number of entries, you are risking bugs to occur due to not updating that variable correctly, missing edge cases when to update that variable, etc.

Comment: `view::Player::Player(logic::Player& player) { m_player = &player;}` is indeed pointer within a vector, but that vector is never resized, guess `std::array` would fit better. About my problem... previous version had no bug like that, because I just added `sf::RectangleShape` to `view::Player`, before it was just token bouncing around the board, now it is also represented by `sf::RectangleShape` which meant to be label with player data. About `vector::size()` instead of extra variables, thanks, I realized i dont even need to pass numberOfPlayers, i can just use size of vector instead.

Comment: *but that vector is never resized* -- In all of this code, where is your guarantee of this?  A person's word (and comments in code) are not always the truth.  Like here -- `m_players.push_back(view::Player(m_game.getPlayer(i)));`?  Only the running of the code is the truth.

Comment: You are actually right... `m_players.reserve()` before `push_back` did the job.

Comment: You mean `m_players.resize()`.   Don't use `reserve()`, as that does not logically add entries to the vector.

Comment: In my case `reserve()` worked, from what I understand, it should allocate enough memory to hold given elements, in my case `reserve(4)` was enough since 4 is maximum number of players. I did `reserve()` before I started to `push_back` elements, is it really considered a bad idea ?

Comment: Calling `reserve()` is ok before `push_back`.  I was mistaken that you were accessing the vector using `[ ]` after calling `reserve`.  What raised my suspicion is that pointers to vector elements are dangerous, unless you can guarantee that the vector is never resized passed its capacity, and that isn't so trivial in large programs.